# Auto-arrange UML diagrams in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

I'm creating UML diagrams (use case and class diagrams) in Visual Studio 2010 for a new project. Instead of using drag and drop to place all the model elements in a visually pleasing way, I would like to automatically arrange the diagrams, to save time. Is that possible in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate? In other VS2010 editions?

Comment: Do you mean in a useful manner or just so that they don't overlap too much?

Comment: avoiding overlaps would already be very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the kind of diagrams you are making, there is often a *Rearrange layout* icon enabled in the Modelling toolbar. Also, right click on the background of the diagram to be able to find and select that option. However, I'm not sure if you are going to be satisfied of the result of the auto-arrange capabilities of VS2010.

For example, in the sequence diagram, click the layout icon left of **Create Work Item**:
[image]

(this is not available in the Class diagram)

Only the VS2010 Ultimate edition allows modelling projects, so that answers the second part of your question.

Comment: What do you mean with "there is often ...", I can't find that option in VS2010 Ultimate trial. Thanks for the answer to the second question.

Comment: Not all diagrams offer that option. I adjusted my answer to make that clear.

Comment: I see. That button is disabled in the diagrams I want to use it.